# Fragment must be a public static class to be properly recreated from instance state?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentmanager

After updating to the support repository,

```
compile('com.android.support:support-v4:26.+') {
    force = true
}
compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+') {
    force = true
}
compile('com.android.support:design:26.+') {
    force = true
}
compile('com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+') {
    force = true
}
compile('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+') {
    force = true
}
```

I'm getting this weird exception.

> TransactionDetailsFragment must be a public static class to be  properly recreated from instance state

Here is a my source code

```
public class TransactionDetailsViewFragment extends MainFragment implements FragmentWithKeepPrevious, FragmentWithName, FragmentWithBackAction {
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private PagerTitleStrip mPagerTitleStrip;
private View mView;
private int transaclionPosition;
private List<Transaction> cashTransactions;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_transaction_details_view, container, false);
    mViewPager = mView.findViewById(R.id.u_transaction_details_viewpager_3);
    mPagerTitleStrip = mView.findViewById(R.id.u_transaction_details_header);
    try {
        cashTransactions = new ArrayList<>();
        if (GlobalClassParameters.transactions != null) {
            cashTransactions = GlobalClassParameters.transactions;
        }
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (cashTransactions != null)
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
    mPagerTitleStrip.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {

        transaclionPosition = bundle.getInt("transactionPosition");
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(transaclionPosition);
    }
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            try {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });


    return mView;
}


void syncTitles() {
    for (int counter = 0; counter < mPagerTitleStrip.getChildCount(); counter++) {
        if (mPagerTitleStrip.getChildAt(counter) instanceof TextView) {
            TextView textView = ((TextView) mPagerTitleStrip.getChildAt(counter));
            UniPAYTypefaceUtils.setLocalisation(textView, getActivity(), TextStyle.LIGHT);
            textView.setTextSize(14);
        }
    }
}

private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        TransactionDetailsFragment transactionDetailsFragment = new TransactionDetailsFragment();
        transactionDetailsFragment.setTransaction(cashTransactions.get(position).getTransactionDetails().getTransactionView());
        transactionDetailsFragment.setTransactionButtons(cashTransactions.get(position).getTransactionDetails().getTransationButton());
        transactionDetailsFragment.setmTransactionPosition(position);
        syncTitles();

        return transactionDetailsFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cashTransactions.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String title = cashTransactions.get(position).getName();
        SpannableString whiteSpannable = new SpannableString(title);
        return whiteSpannable;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onBack() {
    transaclionPosition = 0;
    return true;
}

@Override
public int getName() {
    return R.string.u_transaction_details;
}

@Override
public Class getBackFragment() {
    transaclionPosition = 0;
    return HistoryFragment.class;


}

public class TransactionDetailsFragment extends Fragment {
    private List<KeyValueParams> mTransaction;
    private List<TransationButton> transationButtons;
    private int mTransactionPosition = -1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_transaction_details, container, false);
        CustomRecyclerView listView =  view.findViewById(R.id.u_transaction_details);

        if (mTransaction != null) {
            final KeyValueRecyclerViewAdapter keyValueAdapter = new KeyValueRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), mTransaction);
            listView.setAdapter(keyValueAdapter);
            listView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
            keyValueAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.t_datetime)).setText(cashTransactions.get(mTransactionPosition).getDatetime());


        return view;
    }

    public void setTransaction(List<KeyValueParams> mTransaction) {
        this.mTransaction = mTransaction;
    }

    public void setTransactionButtons(List<TransationButton> transactionButtons) {
        this.transationButtons = transactionButtons;
    }

    public void setmTransactionPosition(int position) {
        this.mTransactionPosition = position;
    }
}
}
```

As you can see, I'm using ViewPager and and PagerTitleStrip inside Viewpager.   Here is my xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:clickable="true">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/u_header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/u_transaction_details_viewpager_3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:id="@+id/u_transaction_details_header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/u_common_margin_left"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/u_common_margin_right"
            android:background="@color/u_pink_light"
            android:padding="@dimen/u_common_text_size_small"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I try to go my Fragment,I have this exception 
Can anyone tell me what's wrong in my source or how I can write my code to can run without exceptions in new support library?

Comment: The error complains about `TransactionDetailsFragment` but you show code for `TransactionDetailsViewFragment`. These are not the same thing.

Comment: @Code scroll to the bottom

Comment: you can add @SuppressLint("ValidFragment") to Fragment like   
   @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public class TransactionDetailsFragment extends Fragment {

Answer (score 3):

You should make TransactionDetailsFragment an entirely separate Java file, or make it a `public static class`, as the error says.

This has nothing to do with your Gradle dependencies, although you honestly should avoid using a `+` in any dependency